# USB keyboard works in GRUB only after pressing the reset button on the case

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, keyboard

My PC is set to dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

When I power on my PC or reboot from any OS, GRUB menu is appear but my USB keyboard not working in it... and the keyboard's LEDs don't blink.
But if I restart my PC using the button on the case, then everything works great! Keyboard's LEDs blink before GRUB, I can select either OS and boot into it.

Is it possible that the reason is in my GRUB settings?

My PC hardware:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H
- Keyboard: SVEN KB-C7100EL
- SSD: INTEL SSDSC2CW240A3 (Windows and Ubuntu are installed on it)

My BIOS settings:

- Fast Boot: Disabled
- Legacy USB Support: Enabled

Comment: Do you have setting(s) for USB keyboard or full USB support or similar? Windows & Ubuntu have their own drivers for keyboard, but grub tries to use UEFI/BIOS driver.

Comment: @oldfred My BIOS have: _Legacy USB Support_ it's enabled, _XHCI Hand-off_ - enabled, _EHCI Hand-off_ - disabled, _XHCI Mode_ - Smart Auto (also possible 'Auto', 'Enabled', 'Disabled', 'Manual'). Maybe I should try to playing with them...

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: My Asus is Z97, so similar Intel based settings. Just different vendor's UEFI shows them somewhat differently. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2

Comment: @heynnema It returned:  F9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was somewhat unexpected...

When I switched **XHCI Mode** in BIOS from 'Smart Auto' to just 'Auto', my keyboard started working in the GRUB.

@oldfred, @heynnema thank you very much! You helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**keyboard**

Confirm that the keyboard is plugged into a motherboard SYSTEM USB port, not a PCIe USB card port.

**BIOS**

Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H

You have BIOS version F9, dated 3/19/2014.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F10b, dated 6/12/2014, for rev 1.0 motherboards, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z87X-UD3H-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios).

Note: This is marked as a beta. Also download the F9 BIOS file, just in case you need to downgrade.

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: GRUB behaves the same when the keyboard is in PCIe USB card and when it is in SYSTEM USB port.

The word "beta" in the title confuses me a little. :)
I will try to update BIOS if other methods do not help.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @VladimirD. You should have it plugged into a system USB port. There may be a problem with the keyboard. Do you have another one to try? Beta usually means a testing version, or fast patch version, not a final release version. Normally I wouldn't recommend a beta version, but F10b has been up since 2014, so it's probably ok. But just in case of trouble, that's why I said to also download the F9 version, just in case. Try a different keyboard first however.

Comment: @VladimirD. Status please...

Comment: Do I need to change status of question? or? Sorry I'm new here...

Comment: @VladimirD. Just come back and accept the answer that you posted. Glad it's working for you now.